# ./byfn.sh -m generate give errors

Tags: hyperledger

According to HyperLedger official [Tutorial Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGSKV.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGSKV.png): http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/build_network.html, I tried to run `./byfn.sh -m generate` but the output consists of errors:

`

- configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
  2018-06-15 14:28:54.070 +07 [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
  2018-06-15 14:28:54.101 +07 [common/configtx/tool/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Error unmarshaling config into struct:  4 error(s) decoding:
- '' has invalid keys: capabilities
- 'Profiles[TwoOrgsChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Capabilities
- 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis]' has invalid keys: Capabilities
- 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Orderer' has invalid keys: Capabilities
- res=1
- set +x
  `

I got some error message I feel like I missed some configuration but I had no idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now the error is resolved thanks to suggestion from my senior suggesting that from [the documents](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/samples.html) I should change version of **bash**

```
curl -sSL <link-to-file> | bash -s 1.1.0
```